# Can't convert deserialized JObject to SQLiteCommand datatype

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Problem: I can't cast or convert a deserialized `JObject` to a variable with datatype `SQLiteCommand`.

---

What am I doing is: I want to make 2-step update for my application. My database is SQLite, so no stored procedure.

- First step is a local version on the current user machine/PC (Can only see in this computer and not yet saved in main database). To achieve this, the program will serialize all the pending sql queries (this one I have succeeded), that the user want to execute, in different json files.
- When an admin approved these changes, the queries will be deserialized, then it will be executed. The update now in the database, and other computers can read these changes too. (This part I have not succeeded)

---

Codes:

```
// Serialize the query into a .json file
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
...
// Get the SQLCommand to execute with a connection
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

// Exception occures in the next line
SQLiteCommand commandAgain = (SQLiteCommand)myObject;
```

`jsonString`:

- Literal string:

`"{\"CommandText\":\"Update Tool Set WerkzeugName = $werkzeugname where Id = 2 \",\"CommandTimeout\":30,\"CommandType\":1,\"Connection\":null,\"Parameters\":[{\"Command\":null,\"IsNullable\":true,\"DbType\":16,\"Direction\":1,\"ParameterName\":\"$werkzeugname\",\"Size\":0,\"SourceColumn\":null,\"SourceColumnNullMapping\":false,\"SourceVersion\":512,\"Value\":\"qwe\",\"TypeName\":null,\"Precision\":0,\"Scale\":0}],\"Transaction\":null,\"UpdatedRowSource\":0,\"DesignTimeVisible\":true,\"Site\":null,\"Container\":null}"`.

- Readable version:

```
{
  "CommandText": "Update Tool Set WerkzeugName = $werkzeugname where Id = 2 ",
  "CommandTimeout": 30,
  "CommandType": 1,
  "Connection": null,
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Command": null,
      "IsNullable": true,
      "DbType": 16,
      "Direction": 1,
      "ParameterName": "$werkzeugname",
      "Size": 0,
      "SourceColumn": null,
      "SourceColumnNullMapping": false,
      "SourceVersion": 512,
      "Value": "qwe",
      "TypeName": null,
      "Precision": 0,
      "Scale": 0
    }
  ],
  "Transaction": null,
  "UpdatedRowSource": 0,
  "DesignTimeVisible": true,
  "Site": null,
  "Container": null
}
```

`myObject` is not null. It has the datatype of `System.Object`. From what I saw in the Debugger, it had the right data.

---

The exception: `System.InvalidCastException: The object of type" Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject "can not be converted to type" System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand ".`

---

What I tried so far:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(PendingQueryFilePath))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    return (SQLiteCommand)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(SQLiteCommand));
}
```

```
// Not working because SQLiteCommand did not inherit needed Interface
var convert = Convert.ChangeType(myObject, typeof(SQLiteCommand));
```

```
// Return null
var convert = myObject as SQLiteCommand;
```

**Edit:**

```
// Deliever same exception
var otherObject= (SQLiteCommand) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var otherObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLiteCommand>(jsonString);
var otherObject= (SQLiteCommand) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLiteCommand>(jsonString);
```

Other note:

I did success deserialized other classes that I wrote myself, but not with SQLiteCommand.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(ModifiedContentFilePath))
{
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   return (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyClass));
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
var test = (myObject as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).ToObject<SQLiteCommand>();

This triggers following exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: The object of type" Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject 
"can not be converted to type" System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter".
```

**Last Edit**
To reproduce this error, copy this code and run in visual studio. Framework JSon.net and SQlite in Nuget are needed.
https://rextester.com/OBMA43154

**Solution**: Following @Chetan Ranpariya advice in the comment.

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLiteCommand>(jsonString)`? What does a serialization of a actual SQLiteCommand give you as string? Does that match with what you have?

Comment: Instead of SqliteCommand you should create your own class with properties string CommandText, but CommandType and Dictionary<string, object> Parameters. Create object of this class set the properties and json serialize it. At the other end create a class wit same properties and deserialize the json to an object of that class. Then create new SqliteCommand object using these properties and execute it.

Comment: You can't cast `JObject` to anything, call `.ToObject<T>` instead.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel the value of `jsonString` that I posted above is the value I have from the .json file, also as a return value. 
And I did try your way. `var otherObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLiteCommand>(jsonString);` has save exception.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I tried your suggestion. It also triggered an exception. More details is in my Edit 2 up above :).

Comment: I wouldn't care to serialize the object, just recreate it with the basic properties as @ChetanRanpariya suggests, it's a more foolprove approach, and who knows you might change your database connection in the long run

Comment: `var anotherCommand = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLiteCommand>(json);` should work fine... what issue did you face when you try to deserialize using this approach?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya with `json == jsonString from me above`. That line of code create this exception: `System.InvalidCastException: The object of type" Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject 
"can not be converted to type" System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter"`

Comment: So it looks like JSON desrialization of SqLiteParameter is not possible via NewtonSoft.Json.... You can either write custom JSON handler to deserialize SqLiteParameter or you can use the approach which I suggested earlier.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes. I am following your earlier suggestion :). It is the only and best possible way for me right now.

Comment: Not Only SqLiteParameter, even SQLParameter have the same issue...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya How did you find that out? I also earlier try to find documentation if Json can't work with some type of framework/ class datatype but not found any.

Comment: I tried running sample code to seriailize and deserialize SqLiteCommand and SQLCommand classes with parameters added to them.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you again for your time and idea. I really appreciate it.